# rbind 2 data frames by the elements in 2 columns, avoiding nested loops

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, apply, rbind

I have two data frames like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Marker1=c('+','+','+','-','-'), Marker2=c('+','+','+','+','-'), Marker3=c('+','-','+','-','+'),
                  Sample=c(1,1,2,3,3), Population_ID=c(1,2,1,5,6), Cells_in_Sample=c(443,23,567,98,3))
df2 <- data.frame(Population_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6),
                  Marker1=c('+','+','+','+',NA,NA,NA,'+','+','+','+',NA,NA,NA,'-','-','-','-',NA,NA,NA,'-','-','-','-',NA,NA,NA),
                  Marker2=c('+','+',NA,NA,'+','+',NA,'+','+',NA,NA,'+','+',NA,'+','+',NA,NA,'+','+',NA,'-','-',NA,NA,'-','-',NA),
                  Marker3=c('+',NA,'+',NA,'+',NA,'+','-',NA,'-',NA,'-',NA,'-','-',NA,'-',NA,'-',NA,'-','+',NA,'+',NA,'+',NA,'+'))
```

They look like this:

```
> df1
  Marker1 Marker2 Marker3 Sample Population_ID Cells_in_Sample
1       +       +       +      1             1             443
2       +       +       -      1             2              23
3       +       +       +      2             1             567
4       -       +       -      3             5              98
5       -       -       +      3             6               3
> head(df2)
  Population_ID Marker1 Marker2 Marker3
1             1       +       +       +
2             1       +       +    <NA>
3             1       +    <NA>       +
4             1       +    <NA>    <NA>
5             1    <NA>       +       +
6             1    <NA>       +    <NA>
```

`df1` contains my "base" populations with combinations of 3 markers (all 3 present), plus the counts (`Cells_in_Sample`) of each population per Sample.

`df2` takes the unique combinations of 3 markers and makes all the possible combinations of 1 and 2 out of them. Note that `df2` already includes the "base" populations from `df1`.

What I want to do here is just produce a `final_df` combining both, in an efficient and elegant way, avoiding nested loops if possible.

The `final_df` should preserve the Sample and counts values for each "base" 3-marker combination in `df1`, extended to all the "sub-combinations" in `df2`. Thus, I should `rbind` them by `Sample` and `Population_ID`.

Now I managed to do this, using nested `for` loops, but I am wondering whether there is a better solution.

This is what I have done:

```
final_df <- NULL
for (s in unique(df1$Sample)){
  df1_sub <- subset(df1, Sample==s)
  for (p in df1_sub$Population_ID){
    df1_sub_sub <- subset(df1_sub, Population_ID==p)
    df2_sub <- subset(df2, Population_ID==p)
    df2_sub$Sample <- s
    df2_sub$Cells_in_Sample <- df1_sub_sub$Cells_in_Sample
    df2_sub <- df2_sub[,c(2,3,4,5,1,6)]
    #note there is no need to rbind df1_sub_sub and df2_sub
    #cause df2 already contains the populations from df1
    final_df <- rbind(final_df, df2_sub)
  }
}
```

`final_df` looks exactly like I want. I paste it full below for reference:

```
> final_df
    Marker1 Marker2 Marker3 Sample Population_ID Cells_in_Sample
1         +       +       +      1             1             443
2         +       +    <NA>      1             1             443
3         +    <NA>       +      1             1             443
4         +    <NA>    <NA>      1             1             443
5      <NA>       +       +      1             1             443
6      <NA>       +    <NA>      1             1             443
7      <NA>    <NA>       +      1             1             443
8         +       +       -      1             2              23
9         +       +    <NA>      1             2              23
10        +    <NA>       -      1             2              23
11        +    <NA>    <NA>      1             2              23
12     <NA>       +       -      1             2              23
13     <NA>       +    <NA>      1             2              23
14     <NA>    <NA>       -      1             2              23
15        +       +       +      2             1             567
16        +       +    <NA>      2             1             567
17        +    <NA>       +      2             1             567
18        +    <NA>    <NA>      2             1             567
19     <NA>       +       +      2             1             567
20     <NA>       +    <NA>      2             1             567
21     <NA>    <NA>       +      2             1             567
151       -       +       -      3             5              98
161       -       +    <NA>      3             5              98
171       -    <NA>       -      3             5              98
181       -    <NA>    <NA>      3             5              98
191    <NA>       +       -      3             5              98
201    <NA>       +    <NA>      3             5              98
211    <NA>    <NA>       -      3             5              98
22        -       -       +      3             6               3
23        -       -    <NA>      3             6               3
24        -    <NA>       +      3             6               3
25        -    <NA>    <NA>      3             6               3
26     <NA>       -       +      3             6               3
27     <NA>       -    <NA>      3             6               3
28     <NA>    <NA>       +      3             6               3
```

Is there a straightforward and efficient way to do this without nested loops? My actual data is many times bigger than this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this just a merge/join? `merge(df2, df1[c("Population_ID","Sample","Cells_in_Sample")], by="Population_ID")` ?

Comment: not really... cause you have multiple entries of the same `Population_ID` in `df1` associated to different `Samples`, and sample information is not available in `df2`

Comment: Actually, @thelatemail is right, see my answer.

Comment: Ok I'm dumb, it was indeed an easy one! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need loops at all, this is a case for [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).
In the code below I make a copy of `final_df` just for test purposes, to keep the expected result as it was.

```r
df3 <- final_df
row.names(df3) <- NULL

# join removing the marker columns from df1
mrg <- merge(df2, df1[4:6], by = "Population_ID")[c(2:5, 1, 6)]
mrg <- mrg[order(mrg$Sample), ]
row.names(mrg) <- NULL

identical(df3, mrg)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Your desired result can be achieved with a `left_join()`.

1. Drop the Marker columns from `df1` since these are already included in `df2`.
2. `left_join()` the two datasets.
3. Reorder columns and arrange rows to match the result table in your question.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1a <-
  df1 |>
  select(-contains("Marker"))

left_join(df2, df1a, relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  select(contains("Marker"), Sample, everything()) |>
  arrange(Population_ID, Sample)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(Population_ID)`
#>    Marker1 Marker2 Marker3 Sample Population_ID Cells_in_Sample
#> 1        +       +       +      1             1             443
#> 2        +       +    <NA>      1             1             443
#> 3        +    <NA>       +      1             1             443
#> 4        +    <NA>    <NA>      1             1             443
#> 5     <NA>       +       +      1             1             443
#> 6     <NA>       +    <NA>      1             1             443
#> 7     <NA>    <NA>       +      1             1             443
#> 8        +       +       +      2             1             567
#> 9        +       +    <NA>      2             1             567
#> 10       +    <NA>       +      2             1             567
#> 11       +    <NA>    <NA>      2             1             567
#> 12    <NA>       +       +      2             1             567
#> 13    <NA>       +    <NA>      2             1             567
#> 14    <NA>    <NA>       +      2             1             567
#> 15       +       +       -      1             2              23
#> 16       +       +    <NA>      1             2              23
#> 17       +    <NA>       -      1             2              23
#> 18       +    <NA>    <NA>      1             2              23
#> 19    <NA>       +       -      1             2              23
#> 20    <NA>       +    <NA>      1             2              23
#> 21    <NA>    <NA>       -      1             2              23
#> 22       -       +       -      3             5              98
#> 23       -       +    <NA>      3             5              98
#> 24       -    <NA>       -      3             5              98
#> 25       -    <NA>    <NA>      3             5              98
#> 26    <NA>       +       -      3             5              98
#> 27    <NA>       +    <NA>      3             5              98
#> 28    <NA>    <NA>       -      3             5              98
#> 29       -       -       +      3             6               3
#> 30       -       -    <NA>      3             6               3
#> 31       -    <NA>       +      3             6               3
#> 32       -    <NA>    <NA>      3             6               3
#> 33    <NA>       -       +      3             6               3
#> 34    <NA>       -    <NA>      3             6               3
#> 35    <NA>    <NA>       +      3             6               3
```